# Get variable from other page variale contain 1 or 2 or 3, jquery function create from for every numbers with same data

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, variables, arraylist

i am developing a page where session pass data through variable.
variable loop and create 1 or 2 or 3 form and every form using dropdwon for selection like

@for ($i = 1; $i < session()->get('benificary')+1; $i++)

```js
<label class="form-label" for="name">Beneficiary Name</label>
<input
  type="text"
  class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror"
  name="name[]"
  value=""
  id="name[]"
  placeholder="Employee Name"
  required
  data-parsley-minlength="6"
/>

<label class="form-label">Beneficiary Relation</label>
<select class="form-control select2" id="relation[]" name="relation[]" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Relation with</option>
</select>

<label class="form-label" for="cnic">Beneficiary CNIC Number</label>
<input
  type="text"
  data-inputmask="'mask': '54400-0120001-0'"
  class="form-control @error('cnic') is-invalid @enderror"
  name="cnic[]"
  value=""
  id="cnic[]"
  placeholder="54400-0120001-1"
  required
  data-parsley-minlength="15"
/>

<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-4">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label">Beneficiary Bank</label>
    <select
      class="form-control select2"
      id="bank[]"
      name="bank[]"
      required
      data-parsley-minlength="1"
    >
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Beneficiary Bank</option>
    </select>

    <label class="form-label">Beneficiary Bank Branch</label>
    <select
      class="form-control select2 Subbanks"
      id="Subbanks[]"
      name="branch[]"
      required
      data-parsley-minlength="1"
    >
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Bank Branch</option>
    </select>

    <label class="form-label" for="account">Bank Account No</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control @error('account') is-invalid @enderror"
      name="account[]"
      value=""
      id="account[]"
      placeholder="Enter Account No"
      required
      data-parsley-minlength="8"
    />

    <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```

@endfor

how get every from with uniq id of dropdown

Comment: You may have a look of Jquery [html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/)